# ¿Es verdad que «advertir» puede significar «to notice something»?

Tags: definiciones

Según [Wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/advertir#Spanish), una definición de «advertir» es:

> to notice something

Pero [RAE](http://dle.rae.es/advertir) no dice lo mismo, o por lo menos no en esos terminos.  ¿Se equivoca Wiktionary?  Sí no, me puede dar un ejemplo de como usar «advertir» en el sentido de «to notice something»?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Sí, puede tener también ese significado. La acepción de ‘poner algo en conocimiento de alguien’, es mucho más común que la otra, pero incluso en la explicación del link que incluyes en la pregunta se puede ver que uno de los significados es:

> Fijar en algo la atención, **reparar, observar**

Puede resultar un poco más claro en [esta otra entrada](http://lema.rae.es/dpd/srv/search?id=y4HMJ3r3wD6MrVMLgg), que explica:

> Cuando significa ‘darse cuenta [de algo] o reparar [en algo]’, es transitivo

Así que, `advertir` puede significar "darse cuenta de algo / to notice something"

[Esta otra web](http://es.thefreedictionary.com/advirti%C3%B3) proporciona un par de ejemplos muy ilustrativos

> Nada más llegar, **advirtieron** que no eran bien recibidos.
>
> En la imagen de la fotografía **advertimos** una gran variedad de efectos cromáticos.